# SQL create a datetime from year and number fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two columns in a view which give me date parts.

They are month number and year.

I need a new column which is a date/time field. it needs to be the first of the month and year the other two columns provide.

i.e `4, 2011` need to be

```
2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
```

in the new column

Current set up looks like this:

```
month_number    incident_year
4   2011
5   2011
6   2011
7   2011
8   2011
9   2011
10  2011
11  2011
12  2011
1   2012
2   2012
3   2012
4   2012
5   2012
6   2012
```

Comment: You just need the column as output for the query, right? Or are you trying to add a new column to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Select CAST(CAST( incident_year AS varchar(4)) + '-' + 
        CAST(month_number AS varchar(2)) + '-01' AS DATETIME) as incident_Year
 from YourView
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work: `CAST(month_number AS varchar)` will return `'4'`, not `'04'`.

Comment: @X-Zero the leading zero is not actually required with default settings (though I'm not sure about all languages or dateformat settings). Also as the (now deleted) comment stated: [stop declaring varchar without length. Please.](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)

Comment: @X-Zero i doubt that .Even adding 4 will return you 04

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
  incident_year, month_number,
  dt = DATEADD(MONTH, (incident_year-1900)*12+month_number-1, '19000101') 
  FROM dbo.view_name;
```

You can also make it a little less verbose by using the 0-date:

```
SELECT 
  incident_year, month_number,
  dt = DATEADD(MONTH, (incident_year-1900)*12+month_number-1, 0) 
  FROM dbo.view_name;
```

In SQL Server 2012 you will be able to do this much simpler:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(incident_year, month_number, 1)
  FROM dbo.view_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter table yourTable add newDateColumn datetime NULL

update yourTable set newDateColumn = 
   CONVERT(datetime, CAST(incident_year as varchar(4)) +'-' CAST(month_number as varchar(2))+'-01 00:00:00.000', varchar(30)) 
   from YourTable
```